# 2d to 3d image/video conversion using Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, 3d, 2d, video-processing

I want to develop 3D image/video processing algorithm but I don't have 3D camera.
I know that 3D image/video can be extract from 2D image/video using one of the methods mentioned [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.100.2308&rep=rep1&type=pdf).
Is there any Matlab implementation/toolbox exist to such algorithm?

Comment: It is not straight 2D to 3D conversion as you mentioned. It is actually adding disparity information to the 2D image. To do so you should have a stereo-camera.

Comment: Which of the methods are suitable for your application? Some of them require 2 Cameras, some don't apply to moving cameras, some require artificial light patterns, some methods require multiple camera frames to capture one depth image making them impractical for moving objects or cameras.